# Error messag pop up, when i start any solution in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

below error message pop-ups whenever i start any **solutions**.....of **VS2010**

what should i have to do for come out of it???

[image: Error Message Every time i start any solutions of VS2010]

Comment: Have you done as it says? What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this fellow](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-localappdata-environment-variable-in-windows-xp/) explains the solution very well for you:

**Add LOCALAPPDATA Environment Variable in Windows XP**

`LOCALAPPDATA` is one of the new environment variables included in Windows Vista, which points to the folder that stores the data for local (non-roaming) applications. To access the folder, run the command `%LOCALAPPDATA%` from Start, Search box in Windows Vista. **This variable does not exist in earlier Windows Operating Systems. If you access this folder frequently in your Windows XP system, you may add the `LOCALAPPDATA` variable using the steps below.**

Note: Alternately, you can open the Local Application Data folder in Windows XP and Windows Vista by running the command `shell:Local AppData.`

**Add `LOCALAPPDATA` variable in Windows XP**

- Right-click on the My Computer icon
  and choose Properties
- Click Advanced
- Click Environment Variables
- Under User variables section, click
  New
- In the Variable name: field, type
  LOCALAPPDATA
- In the Variable value: field, type %USERPROFILE%\Local
  Settings\Application Data
- Click OK, OK, OK to close the dialog
  boxes.

The `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variable is now added.

Since this is a "user" variable you won't have to reboot to use the variable.

Comment: You don't need to reboot for per-user environmental variables. A logoff/on will work. However in this case any new processes launched from Explorer will set the new values immediately (other existing processes not coded to pick up env changes immediately will not see the change until they are restarted).

Comment: @Richard, thanks for the clarification. I have scratched my head many times over newly-created environment variables that just aren't there until I finally remember to reboot. And it can be a real pain if you're setting the variable on a server. But in this case, you're right. I'll revise my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you so much its done now i am not getting error ........

Answer (score 1):

Probably this may help you:
http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=293